# Using phoenix_api_docs

Tags: node.js, api, documentation, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to use https://github.com/smoku/phoenix_api_docs to make a doc api, but I have a problem, as indicated in the documentation, I put in the test_helper.exs this:

```
PhoenixApiDocs.start ExUnit.start(formatters: [ExUnit.CLIFormatter, PhoenixApiDocs.Formatter])
```

when I run mix test, the console shows me this:

```
09:22:51.173 [error] GenEvent handler PhoenixApiDocs.Formatter
                     installed in #PID<0.323.0> terminating
  ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function
    WhitespaceEx.Application.Router.__routes__/0 is undefined (module 
    WhitespaceEx.Application.Router is not available)
    WhitespaceEx.Application.Router.__routes__() (phoenix_api_docs)
  lib/phoenix_api_docs/generator.ex:26: 
    PhoenixApiDocs.Generator.routes_docs/2 (phoenix_api_docs) 
  lib/phoenix_api_docs/generator.ex:12:
    PhoenixApiDocs.Generator.run/0 (phoenix_api_docs) 
  lib/phoenix_api_docs/formatter.ex:22: 
    PhoenixApiDocs.Formatter.save_blueprint_file/0 (phoenix_api_docs) 
  lib/phoenix_api_docs/formatter.ex:9: 
    PhoenixApiDocs.Formatter.handle_event/2 (stdlib) 
  gen_event.erl:573: :gen_event.server_update/4 (stdlib) 
  gen_event.erl:555: :gen_event.server_notify/4 (stdlib) 
  gen_event.erl:296: :gen_event.handle_msg/6 (stdlib) 
  proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3 Last message: 
    {:suite_finished, 6679713, nil}
```

and the documentation in a file api.apib is not generated. The project configuration has `erlang 19.2`, `elixir 1.4.2`, `Phoenix v1.2.4`, `nodejs 7.4.0`, `Erlang/OTP 20`

I would like some help in this case

Answer (score 0):

`phoenix_api_docs` infers the name of your router module from the application module specified in `mix.exs`:

```
  def run do
    test_conns = PhoenixApiDocs.ConnLogger.conns
    app_module = Mix.Project.get.application |> Keyword.get(:mod) |> elem(0)
    router_module = Module.concat([app_module, :Router])

    %{
      host: Keyword.get(api_docs_info, :host, "http://localhost"),
      title: Keyword.get(api_docs_info, :title, "API Documentation"),
      description: Keyword.get(api_docs_info, :description, "Enter API description in mix.exs - api_docs_info"),
      routes: routes_docs(router_module, test_conns)
    }
  end
```

From your error message, it looks like your application module name is `WhitespaceEx.Application`, but I guess your router module is `WhitespaceEx.Router`.

One way to make this work with the current `phoenix_api_docs` implementation would be to rename your application module to `WhitespaceEx`.

There is an open PR that will allow you to configure the router name, and support the phoenix 1.3 conventions [Support for Phoenix 1.3 #9](https://github.com/smoku/phoenix_api_docs/pull/9)